# How to restrict DI from using the sub-class

Tags: java, spring

We have a situation, where we have a base security model and then an extended security model. We intend to use the base-model for internal users and extended-model for public interaction. Obviously, extended-model requires extra security checks. Hence, extended-security class extends the base-security class.

This creates an issue with Spring dependency injection(4.3.5) with Play Framework 2.5. If the Extended class has already been instantiated, then DI injects the "Extended" instance even if our code specifies a Base class as follows: @Security.Authenticated(BaseAuthenticator.class). On the other hand, if the Extended class is NOT available, then DI injects the BaseAuthenticator class. Hence, we get an un-deterministic result.

What we would like to achieve is: 
1) @Security.Authenticated(BaseAuthenticator.class) ==> should always use the BaseAuthenticator
2) @Security.Authenticated(ExtendedAuthenticator.class)  ==> should always use the ExtendedAuthenticator

Wondering, if this is the right behavior?

Is there a way to hard-wire it to a "particular" class, and not the subclasses?

Comment: What about changing inheritance a bit? Still have `ExtendedAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator` but introduce `SimpleAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator` with no additional logic at all. And use @Security.Authenticated(SimpleAuthenticator.class). You can even make the `BaseAuthenticator` abstract to prevent creation.

Comment: Absolutely, we can work around this by breaking the hierarchy in our model, but wanted to know if there is a better solution out there or we are missing some DI specific tweaking.